# C++, что значит наследование enum class

Tags: c++, enum-class

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
enum class Enum : uint8_t
{
    // ...
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я понимаю, что данное `наследование`(если это можно так назвать) позволяет задать размер типа?

Например, у меня есть `DLL` и в ней есть функция, которая принимает указатель на структуру, в которой есть некие данные. Могу ли я (ради удобства) использовать в этой структуре поле не типа `uint8_t`, а типа `enum class .. : uint8_t`?

Например:

```
enum class Code : uint8_t
{
    // ...
};    

struct Message
{
    Code code;
    // ...
};
```

С таким кодом было бы намного удобнее работать, потому что сразу было бы понятно, за что отвечает поле `code` и какие возможные значения оно может принять. Единственная опасность заключается в том, что в поле могут попасть значения, для которых в `enum class` нет соответствия.

Все ли я верно понимаю?

Comment: @AlexF, поясните, пожалуйста, про значения, которым нет соответствия в перечислении. Ведь *enum class* не поддерживает неявное преобразование типов. Соответственно, как мне кажется, некорректное значение случайно в такую переменную  попасть не может. Или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Comment: @AlexF, я почему и спросил, что, с одной стороны,  с помощью *static_cast* на мой взгляд - это уже не совсем случайно, с другой стороны, я не очень понимаю, как сработает преобразование, если в перечислении нет соответствия преобразовываемому числу.

Comment: @AlexF Под *случайно* я рассматривал формулировку "могут попасть". Спасибо за разъяснения, я понял проблему с преобразованием.